# TensorFlow for Mac: error importing tensorflow

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, importerror

I'm trying to use TensorFlow on my Mac.

I'm in terminal and have followed all directions on the Tensorflow Install page until "Run a short test program"

I'm attempting to write

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

But I receive the following message

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/robilin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: please format your exception so that others can read it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have an incompatible numpy version.

You need to upgrade numpy

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```

to upgrade numpy to its latest version